# flutter BottomAppBar notchMargin transparent color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

Hey! i want to know how i can change the transparent background to bottomAppBar ,
knowing that I user `extendBody: true`  in `Scaffold` ,But it didn't work

**scaffold:**

```
 return Scaffold(
            extendBody: true,
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: defaultColor,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Icon(Icons.qr_code_2),
            ),
            body: ShopLayoutCubit.get(context).pages[index],
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            bottomNavigationBar: TabBarNavigation(
              index: index,
              onChangeTab: onTabTapped,
            ),
          );
```

**TabBarNavigation:**

```
 return BottomAppBar(
      shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      notchMargin: 15.0,
     
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 80,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                buildTabItem(
                  index: 0,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.house,
                    size: 21,
                  ),
                ),
                buildTabItem(
                    index: 1,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.cartShopping,
                      size: 21,
                    )),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                ),
                buildTabItem(
                    index: 2,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart,
                      size: 21,
                    )),
                buildTabItem(
                    index: 3,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.solidUser,
                      size: 21,
                    )),
              ])),
    );
```

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it's done !!!!!

Comment: When you came to a solution I'd recommend clsoing this question or marking it as solved. For others having the same issue it would be a great idea to share your solution as an answer to this post.

Comment: There are missing widgets in this snippet and failed to reproduce the issue. I modified the unavailable parts and seems everything is working fine.